# Kaitai Struct: calculated instances with a condition

Tags: python, data-structures, reverse-engineering, kaitai-struct

I'm trying to get Kaitai Struct to reverse engineer a binary structure. `seq` fields work as intended, but `instances` don't seem to work as I want them to.

My binary format includes a header with a list of constants that I parse as `header` field with `consts` array subfield:

```
types:
  header:
    seq:
      # ...
      - id: consts
        type: u8
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: 0x10
```

However, when I try to use the following declaration:

```
instances:
  index_const:
    value: '_root.header.consts[idx - 0x40]'
    if: idx >= 0x40 and idx <= 0x4f
```

This one is intended to calculate a value of `index_const` by looking up into array of `header.consts` if and only if `idx` is in range of [0x40..0x4f].

I use Python as my target language and I assume that it should generate a code like:

```
    @property
    def index_const(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_m_index_const'):
            return self._m_index_const
        if self.idx >= 64 and self.idx <= 79:
            self._m_index_const = self._root.header.consts[(self.idx - 64)];
            return self._m_index_const
```

However, what I get is:

```
    @property
    def index_const(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_m_index_const'):
            return self._m_index_const

        self._m_index_const = self._root.header.consts[(self.idx - 64)];
        return self._m_index_const
```

Is it just me, am I missing something obvious, or is it a bug in Kaitai Struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I guess it should be considered a bug. At the very least, compiler should either allow to use `if` in value instances and process it properly, or disallow `if` and issue an error message.

Thinking of it, I see no reason why `if` is allowed for regular `instances`, but treated this way for `value` `instances`.

Thanks for reporting it, I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/4).

---

Update: The issue is now marked as closed.

> `if_instances` test now tests that. ... Closing this one as solved.

Comment: Thanks! It's a pity that it's a bug :( Any ideas on workarounds or how much should I wait for a bugfix?

Comment: The simplest workaround would be to just inline whatever you have in `if` at the place you want to access your `index_const` at. It's generally ok to do so in real code, but it can be somewhat tricky for KS internal expression language. I'll try to keep you updated.